# Carrying the rod from the end VS from the middle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

[image: A metal rod with three ring]

How do I prove that if you carry this metal rod from R1 or R3 then, it takes more force(it feels heavier) in comparison to if you carry from R2?

Weight of R1 = Weight of R2 = Weight of R3

Distance between R1 and R2 = distance between R2 and R3

I feel like it has to do with torque but I am not sure. 
Please help me out with any information!!

Answer (score 1):

Draw a [free-body diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body_diagram) and sum the forces and moments (i.e., torques). At every point, the forces in every direction and the moments around every axis must be zero; otherwise, the rod will start to accelerate.

Each free-body diagram will contain three downward forces corresponding to the weights of the mass concentrations, plus a reaction force and moment induced by your grip.

In each case, your grip must apply an upward force to counteract the total weight. In addition, if you hold the rod at the end, your grip must resist a moment that would tend to rotate the rod. If you hold the rod at the center, however, the moments induced by the three weights cancel out, and only the downward force remains.